# amazon S3 URL- only available programatically

Tags: amazon-s3

I was given a url but it does not work. i was told the only way to get the data is to access it programatically. how do i do that!?

here is format of url

S3://com.xxxxxx.feedreader/bill_yyyyyyyyyyyy/processed/

Comment: Maybe you can use [aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access that URL.

Comment: what can i type in the command line? thanks!

Comment: For example: aws-cli s3 ls <url> to list the content of the bucket. Commands such as cp for copying files, rm for deleting, etc. are supported. Check out the aws-cli command line [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#cli-aws-s3).

Comment: sorry tried that. i need line by line code on this please. i need to download it to my desktop.

Comment: im not even sure how to get started. it says i can use windows command line but how do i reference the cloud from that?

Comment: You could use something like `aws s3 sync S3://com.xxxxxx.feedreader/bill_yyyyyyyyyyyy/processed/ C:\TEMP`

Answer (score 0):

This is the S3 pseudo-scheme.

```
s3://bucket-name/key
```

The key can contain additonal appearances of `/` delimiters; the bucket name cannot.

To convert this to an http URL, you have to remove the bucket name -- everything between `s3://` and the **first** `/` and create a URL that looks like this:

```
http://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/key
```

So, this:

```
s3://com.example.random/maybe/path/to/file.txt
```

Becomes this:

```
http://com.example.random.s3.amazonaws.com/maybe/path/to/file.txt
```

It is, of course, inaccurate to say that S3 URLs can only be accessed "programmatically" -- that assertion is actually a little bit amusing for its lack of any definable meaning in this context.

As was pointed out in comments, they may be assuming that you'll be using [aws-cli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), which does support the `s3://` pseudo-scheme.  To figure out how to install it and use it, you will need to read the documentation.

> it says i can use windows command line but how do i reference the cloud from that?

That's what aws-cli is for:  command line access to the AWS cloud.  Install it and try `C:\>aws s3 help`.